# google SignIn in android getting Invalid SHA-1 certificate fingerprint error

Tags: android, sha1, keytool

I want to integrate google SignIn to my android app. I have followed all the steps as per the documents. i have created a cerificate finger print through cmd using the following command.

```
keytool -list -keystore C:\Users\ufxyhy\.android\debug.keystore
```

I have entered the password when it prompted and then I got a key showing as SHA-256, and it shows as invalid fingerprint when creating OAuth client ID.

The result I am getting in cmd is follows

```
Keystore type: JKS
```

Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

androiddebugkey, 18-May-2018, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256):

> 00:00:****************:00:00:00:00:00

It shows as SHA-256, How can I create correct SHA-1 finger print for debug?

Comment: never post your keystore and sha details. its unique to your app. please edit your question or delete and post new.

Comment: edited with dummy value

Comment: do you want to generate sha for debug mode?

Comment: I want both, but when tried with debug, its getting SHA-256 fingerprint and showing invalid when creating OAuth client

Comment: can you try Answer I posted and tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get SHA1 with follow command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}
```

eg:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\me\Desktop\release.jks -alias sample
```

you can also get it in android studio directly as in image
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide default keystore password and key password which you have not provided run below code and check.

```
keytool -list -keystore C:\Users\ufxyhy\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```